# deleteOne() function not working in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I created a basic RESTful API using node,express,mongoDB and mongoose.Postman says that the delete action was completed but It doesn't gets removed from the database

after mongoose removed callbacks it got very confusing

here is the code

```js
.delete(function(req,res){
    // console.log(req.params.articleTitle)
    Article.deleteOne({title: req.params.articleTitle})
    res.send('Deleted')
  })
```

Comment: Would you be willing to share what is in the database after running this? and what is in there before running?

Comment: I'd suggest logging (and sharing with us) the response from the database when calling `deleteOne()`. Separately, what is confusing about the callback removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your other code or error messages I'm going to go out on a limb and say you are moving from callbacks to modern `async/await` pattern and you are having a few issues migrating. Let me know if this works:

```js
.delete(async function(req,res){ //< Make callback async
    // console.log(req.params.articleTitle)
    try{
       const deletedArticle = await Article.deleteOne({title: req.params.articleTitle}) //< await the deletion
       res.send('Deleted')
    }catch(err){
       console.log(err);
       //Handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this it worked, and yeah I am new to async/await the tutorial that  i was following was old and used callbacks.